# Autofilter with date criteria returns blank

Tags: excel, vba, date, variables, autofill

I have the below code to filter data on one sheet with criteria in another sheet. The code seems to work but always just returns blank, not sure why.

Could someone please help?

> ```
> Sub data_test_2()
> '
> ' data_test_2 Macro
> '
>
>
> Dim r As Range, filt As Range, d1 As Long, d2 As Long
> With Worksheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG")
> d1 = .Range("A2").Value
> d2 = .Range("B2").Value
> With Worksheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST")
> .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & CDate(d1)
>
> End With
> End With
> End Sub
> ```

**UPDATE: Code i'm using now works perfect for the filtering bit, just can't seem to copy all of the filtered data and pasted onto the LNG_PORT_23_SG. I'd want to clear any existing data from cell A11 on this sheet and then have the new filtered data copy and pasted.**

> ````
> Option Explicit 
> Sub FilterDates() 
> Dim date1 As Long, date2 As Long, date3 As Long
>
> date1 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A2").Value2 date2 =
> Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("B2").Value2 date3 =
> Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("E2").Value2
>
> With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1:AC1") On Error
> Resume Next .AutoFilter 28, ">=" & 1 * date1, 7 .AutoFilter 29, "<=" &
> 1 * date2, 7 .AutoFilter 9, ">=" & 1 * date3, 7 .AutoFilter Field:=1,
> Criteria1:=Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("C2").Value, Operator:=xlOr,
> Criteria2:=Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("C3").Value
> .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
> Destination:=Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A11")
>
> End With
>
> On Error GoTo 0
>
> End Sub```
> ````

Comment: Is the column `i`, in worksheet `LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST` the one you want to filter? Also, does it contains a real date or text in date format? Even more, if it is a date you don't even need `CDate` as Excel stores it as a number.

Comment: Please,  try adding `,  Operator:=xlFilterValues` after  `Criteria1:=">=" & d1`

Comment: Thank you - removing cdate and adding operator works! One more question, if I want to add a second date criteria to filter a different column, how do I do that? In this case, i'd want the dates in this column to equal my criteria in cell B2 on the other sheet (so not less than or more than but the exact same). Is that possible?

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot filter a second column on the same filter. You must write another similar code line using the appropriate `field` number and `Criteria1`. You can use, but for the same `field`, `Criteria2`, too, or an array for more than two criteria.

Comment: Thanks  - I did try that but get back to the same error where it just goes totally blank. I'm using the below, where the date is either less than or equal to the value in cell B2 (d2). I've tried a few different ways but not sure where i'm going wrong? Help is much appreciated!

With Worksheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST")
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & d1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=29, Criteria2:="<=" & d2, Operator:=xlFilterValues



End With
End With

End Sub```

Comment: Asd13, try recording a macro and filter manually. Excel will provide you with a good example on how to include a second criteria. Also, check https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of observations about your code.

If you intend using variables, always put `Option Explicit` at the top of your procedure – it forces declaration.

Don’t use variable names like `d1` or `d2` because it’s too easy to cause confusion with actual cell addresses.  Also, don’t declare variables you never use.

The following code has been tested and works based on your 2 date columns on the  `LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST` sheet being `I` and `AC`, and your source for the dates being cells `A2` and `B2` on the  `LNG_PORT_23_SG` sheet.  Those cells should be formatted `date`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterDates()
Dim date1 As Long, date2 As Long

date1 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A2").Value2
date2 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("B2").Value2

With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1:AC1")
    .AutoFilter 9, ">=" & 1 * date1, 7
    .AutoFilter 29, "<=" & 1 * date2, 7
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Based on your latest comment regarding the additional criteria - and the desire to copy the filtered data to the `LNG_PORT_23_SG` sheet, please see the amended code below.

**TAKE NOTE** of the option of choosing whether to copy with or without the headings - simply uncomment / delete as appropriate.  Also, please do not use `On Error Resume Next` - it can hide all sorts of problems...

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterDates()
Dim date1 As Long, date2 As Long, date3 As Long, x, y

date1 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A2").Value2
date2 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("B2").Value2
date3 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("E2").Value2
x = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("C2").Value2
y = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("C3").Value2

Application.Goto Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1")
With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 1, x, 2, y, 7
    .AutoFilter 28, ">=" & 1 * date1, 7
    .AutoFilter 29, "<=" & 1 * date2, 7
    .AutoFilter 9, ">=" & 1 * date3, 7
    .Copy Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A11")             '<~~ use this line to copy including headings
    '.Offset(1).Copy Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A11")  '<~~ OR this line to exclude headings
    .AutoFilter
End With

Application.Goto Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! - This worked well, and i've now extended to add some other criteria. One thing i'm trying to do is copy and pasta the filtered values on to "LNG_PORT_23_SG", starting from cell A11. The code i'm using seems to work but it just copies the very first row with all the headings but nothing else. Could you shed some light on where I might be going wrong? Updated the post with the new code. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Kevin9999 this works great! One issue I keep having is that the code doesn't work when the sheet with the data that is being filtered is hidden. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Actually, no problem figured it out with some googling! Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

To answer your comment from kevin9999's respond about needing to copy the filtered result to another sheet, you can do that by changing the following statement from

```
With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1:AC1")
```

to

```
With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

By using `.CurrentRegion`, it automatically selects a continuous range of cells that is associated with `A1`. You would need to ensure that there are no breaks in the columns headers or empty rows though. Note that changing `A1` to `A11` won't change the result as it looks for any continuous cells above, to the left, to the right, and below.

If you do have breaks in the range/table, then another option would be to use a variable to specify the last row and last column of your data.
Or as asked in the comment, you need to only start from cell `A1` you can use this other method.
There are multiple ways to do this, but my preferred method is to use the `Cells.Find()` method:

```
RowNum = Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ColNum = Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```

You can then change the earlier statement to

```
With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(RowNum, ColNum))
```

`Cells(1, 11)` is the same as `A1` while `Cells(RowNum, ColNum)` would be the last column letter and last row from sheet `LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST`.

FYI, your updated code didn't paste correctly so it needs to be reformatted. But something like this should work.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterDates()
Dim date1 As Long, date2 As Long, date3 As Long
Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long

'Set header names
date1 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A2").Value2
date2 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("B2").Value2
date3 = Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("E2").Value2

With Sheets("LNG_PORTFOLIO_2023_SG_HIST").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    On Error Resume Next

    'Filter Data
    .AutoFilter 28, ">=" & 1 * date1, 7
    .AutoFilter 29, "<=" & 1 * date2, 7
    .AutoFilter 9, ">=" & 1 * date3, 7
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("C2").Value, _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("C3").Value
    
    'Identify last row and column of range
    RowNum = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ColNum = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    
    'Copy to another sheet
    .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(RowNum, ColNum)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("LNG_PORT_23_SG").Range("A11")
End With

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```